# Need to replace the first words of each line in several text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, label

I Need to replace the first word (label) of each line in many text files (annotation files). I have written the following script but it doesnt make any cahnge in the text files.

```
 import os

dirname = "/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"
for txt_in in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'r') as f:
        infile = f.read()# Read contents of file
        for line in infile.split('\n') :
            word=line.split(" ")[0]
            if word=="6":
                word=word.replace('6', '5')
            elif word=="9":
                word=word.replace('9', '6')
            elif word=="10":
                word=word.replace('10', '7')
            elif word=="11":
                word=word.replace('11', '8')
            else:
                continue
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'w') as f:
            f.write(infile)
            break
```

Do I have to use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module for this purpose?

You can find a sample .txt (annotation) content at below:
'''

```
0 0.15234375 0.6953125 0.2265625 0.053125

0 0.75078125 0.27890625 0.2046875 0.1546875

0 0.28359375 0.09296875 0.1734375 0.0734375

10 0.31015625 0.634375 0.0890625 0.2625

9 0.37109375 0.35703125 0.0671875 0.2015625

3 0.13671875 0.32265625 0.1609375 0.1390625

1 0.90390625 0.55 0.1390625 0.059375

1 0.946875 0.67890625 0.075 0.0515625

1 0.84921875 0.76171875 0.1609375 0.0515625

3 0.82578125 0.1296875 0.0796875 0.0875
```

'''
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is dirname an directory ?

Comment: You can better make a list and append the change words and then write then write them to the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others your changes are not propagated to the output.

This provides a clearer idea of what you should do.

```
import os

dirname = "/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"
for txt_in in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'r') as f:
        # Don't read entire file since we
        # are looping line by line
        #infile = f.read()# Read contents of file
        result = []
        for line in f:  # changed to file handle
            line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing '\n'
            # Only split once since you're only check the first word
            words = line.split(" ", maxsplit = 1)
            word = words[0]  # word 0 may change
            if word == "6":
                word = word.replace('6', '5')
            elif word=="9":
                word = word.replace('9', '6')
            elif word == "10":
                word = word.replace('10', '7')
            elif word == "11":
                word = word.replace('11', '8')
            else:
                pass
            # Update the word you modified
            words[0] = word  # update word 0
            # save new line into results
            # after converting back to string
            result.append(" ".join(words))

    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'w') as f:
        # Convert result list to string and write to file
        outfile = '\n'.join(result)
        f.write(outfile)
```

Comment: ---> 11             word = word[0]  
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Masoud--couldl you provide some example text for your file?

Comment: @Masoud--made a patch for the IndexError, but I could test if you showed a sample file.

Comment: @DarrylG--I provided a sample .txt file in the edited post. tnx!

Comment: @DarrylG--It worked perfectly.Tnx!
This challenge made me more decisive to learn Python!

Comment: @Masoud--glad I could help.  I learn Python primarily by solving online problems such as through [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/), and trying to answer questions here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214550/discussion-between-masoud-and-darrylg).

Answer (score 1):

You're creating variables like line and word and making changes to them, but these changes are not being reflected in `infile`. You need to either make these changes to `infile` itself, or store the changed stuff in a new variable and write that new variable to the new file.

You can update the code to:

```
outfile = ""
infile = f.read()# Read contents of file
        for line in infile.split('\n') :
            word=line.split(" ")[0]
            if word=="6":
                word=word.replace('6', '5')
            elif word=="9":
                word=word.replace('9', '6')
            elif word=="10":
                word=word.replace('10', '7')
            elif word=="11":
                word=word.replace('11', '8')
            else:
                pass
            newLine = ""
            newLine += word
            for w in line.split(" ")[1:]:
                newLine += w
            newLine += "\n"
            outfile += newLine
```

Now write outfile to the outputfile.

Comment: can you plz give me a clue how i should modify the code to make changes happen in the "infile" itself?

Comment: An easier approach would be to use a new variable.

Comment: I added:
import os

dirname = "/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"
for txt_in in os.listdir('uncorrected-YOLO_darknet/'):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'r') as f:
to the beginning and didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to edit the file you're reading, I'd recommend following a different approach:

1. Create a new file with all the changes, save it.
2. Delete the original file.
3. Rename the new file to original file.

```py
import os


dirname = "/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"
for txt_in in os.listdir('uncorrected-YOLO_darknet'):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'r') as f:
        out_filename = txt_in+"1"
        out_file = open(out_filename, "w")

        for line in f.readlines():
            word = line[0]
            if word == "6":
                line = line.replace('6', '5')
            elif word =="9":
                line = line.replace('9', '6')
            elif word == "10":
                line = line.replace('10', '7')
            elif word == "11":
                line = line.replace('11', '8')
            else:
                continue

            out_file.write(line)
        out_file.close()

    os.remove(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in))
    os.rename(os.path.join(dirname, out_filename), os.path.join(dirname, txt_in))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the path and the “dirname” needs a ‘/‘ at the end of it. Either way the first thing that you may want to check if the files are valid:

```
for txt_in in os.listdir(dirname):

    print(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in)))

    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'r') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a list and append the changed words and then you can write it through file_object.writelines(list)

```
import os

dirname = "/home/masoud/masoud/Dataset/PID-CORRECTED/uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"

for txt_in in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, txt_in), 'r+') as f:
        infile = f.readlines()# Read contents of file
        d=[]
        for line in infile:
            word = line.split(" ")
            if word[0]=="6":
                word[0]="5"
            elif word[0]=="9":
                word[0]= '6'
            elif word[0]=="10":
                word[0]= '7'
            elif word[0]=="11":
                word[0]= '8'
            d.append(" ".join(word))
        if len(d)!=0:
            f.seek(0)
            f.writelines(d)
```

Comment: didnt work.
it made all .txt files the same with unsorted content.

Comment: @Masoud My mistake i just declared the list outside that's why all .txt file where same! Just give it a try and share your output

Comment: plz look at the edited post and the how my original .txt content were.
While they all sorted in one column after running the updated code!

Comment: I think i have found the solution just give it a try and say

Comment: ---> 21             f.seek(len(infile)-2)

ValueError: negative seek position -1

Comment: This error is thrown when there is only one value in the line then this should do it